# Unable to Read Data from Closed Data Group (Outline)

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a sheet with a bunch of excel Data Groups (Outline) which are typically closed or some closed/some open. When using .Offset, it will skip over any of the closed groups which is what is causing me issues, and I wonder what the best way around that is?

Currently, I am using the following VBA to open the groups and then restore their original state, but I wonder if this can be improved upon as iterating through all the rows is pretty inefficient.

```
' Store original state
Dim originalState() As Boolean
ReDim originalState(1 To ws.Rows.Count)
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To ws.Rows.Count
    originalState(i) = ws.Rows(i).ShowDetail
Next i

' Expand all
ws.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=ws.Outline.SummaryRow + 1

' My operations
'....    

' Restore original state
For i = 1 To ws.Rows.Count
    ws.Rows(i).ShowDetail = originalState(i)
Next i
```

Edit: Example of offset use in my code, where searchText(name) is a string from a key (e.g. name=blue and searchText(name) = "Blue squares")

```
Set temp = eConfig.Range("C:C").Find(Trim(searchText(name)), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    ' Due to the merged cells, this shifts temp to non merged cells: the options
Set temp = temp.Offset(0, 3)

' While the next option is greater than the current option i, iterate through
' Finds the length of the options
i = 0
While temp.Offset(i, 0) < temp.Offset(i + 1, 0)
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Data Format:
[image: Example Data (apologies can't show more)]
This is the data where the error first occurs, and I assume subsequent calls to the function with different searchtexts will trigger the same error, when the data groups are closed (level 1), but functions perfectly open (level 2).

Comment: Could you show an example of how you use `.offset`?

Comment: And how do you try "reading from Closed Data Group"? Besides that, placing 1048576  elements in an array, mostly not being part of a group means Excel resources waste. You may try iterating between the `UsedRange` rows, if not possible to detect the last row with values.

Comment: `ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row` will return the last row until you should iterate (instead of 1048576 rows)

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem with `Offset`. The only problem with `Offset` I am aware about is with merged cells. I guess it would be good if you show as screenshot of your data and the relevant code that uses the Offset function

Comment: @FaneDuru Ah yes thanks for catching that... will change that.

Comment: @FunThomas, updated the post hopefully that helps.

Comment: Most probably `Find` did not return anything, not finding a match. You always should use something like: `If Not tmp is Nothing Then` `Set temp = temp.Offset(0, 3)` `Else` `Msgbox Trim(searchText(name)) & " cold not be found..."` `End If`. And what `searchText` function does?

Comment: @FaneDuru SearchText is just a string array with the  name of the item and then the specific text used to find it in the data sheet. So for the posted example it would be searchText = "PCH". The macro works completely normally with the dropdowns open so perhaps find is unable to look through the datagroups?

Comment: So, `name` is a numeric value? Anyhow AFAIK, `Find` is able to deal with hidden rows (dataGroups inclusive). But why don't you proceed as i suggested above and see what's happening? Maybe, you need to add more parameters to the `Find` method. Even if it used to work, if (in the meantime) you searched for a string (even manually) and modified the parameters, it keeps the last used ones (if not mentioned in the call, as needed)...